# Cookies causing trouble - Can't make a cookie stay

Tags: php, post, cookies

I'm having a cookie situation, where my cookies would store a color name or nothing at all. So let's explain it this way. My cookies are related to the look of my website, my website has 3 looks:

- Normal (with no cookie at all)
- Grey (with a cookie set to 'imgit_style' with value "grey")
- Inverted (with cookie set to 'imgit_style' with value "inverted")

I have 3 buttons which trigger the styles to switch. The first button is for **Normal**, it deletes the cookie and makes the look normal.

The second button is for **Grey**, it creates the cookie with name 'imgit_style' and adds a value to it - "grey".

These two work completely fine with each other, but when setting the **Inverted** cookie it wont work! It just gets deleted when I click the third button which should actually replace **Grey** (if it's set) with **Inverted** OR create the cookie if it was unset by the first button.

Hope I was clear enough. Here is my code:

*Styles.php*

```
<?php
$style = '';
if (!isset($_COOKIE['imgit_style']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['green']))
    {
        setcookie('imgit_style', '', time()-31556952);
        $style = '';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['grey']))
    {
        setcookie('imgit_style', 'grey', time()+31556952);
        header('Location: ' . $home_action);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['inverted']))
    {
        setcookie('imgit_style', 'inverted', time()+31556952);
        header('Location: ' . $home_action);
    }
}
else if (isset($_COOKIE['imgit_style']))
{   
    $style =  '_' . $_COOKIE['imgit_style'];
    if (isset($_POST['green']) && $_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'grey' || $_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'inverted')
    {
        setcookie('imgit_style', '', time()-31556952);
        $style = '';
        header('Location: ' . $home_action);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['grey']))
    {
        if ($_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'inverted')
        {
            setcookie('imgit_style', '', time()-31556952);
            if (!isset($_COOKIE['imgit_style']))
            {
                setcookie('imgit_style', 'grey', time()+31556952);
                header('Location: ' . $home_action);
            }
        }
    }
    if (isset($_POST['inverted']))
    {
        if ($_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'grey')
        {
            setcookie('imgit_style', '', time()-31556952);
            if (!isset($_COOKIE['imgit_style']))
            {
                setcookie('imgit_style', 'inverted', time()+31556952);
                header('Location: ' . $home_action);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

---

*header.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<?php include('styles.php'); ?>
<title>IMGit.org - the image host</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/<?php echo 'style' . $style . '.css'; ?>" media="screen" />
<link rel="icon" href="css/images/<?php echo 'favicon' . $style . '.png'; ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="css/images/<?php echo 'favicon' . $style . '.png'; ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
</head>

<body>
<div class="style-switcher">
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="normal" style="vertical-align: text-top;">Switch style:</span>
            <input type="submit" name="green" class="style_green-button" value="green" />
            <input type="submit" name="grey" class="style_grey-button" value="grey" />
            <input type="submit" name="inverted" class="style_inverted-button" value="inverted" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem looks to be that although you call `setcookie()` blank out the cookie value `$_COOKIE` still holds that value for this request. Its contents would not change until the page is reloaded. So you go on to check `!isset($_COOKIE['imgit_style'])`, but that value will still be set unless you explicitly unset it.

```
if (isset($_POST['grey']))
{
    if ($_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'inverted')
    {
        // No need to unset the old one, just overwrite the new one
        // setcookie('imgit_style', '', time()-31556952);
        setcookie('imgit_style', 'grey', time()+31556952);
        header('Location: ' . $home_action);
    }
 }
 if (isset($_POST['inverted']))
 {
    if ($_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'grey')
    {
        // No need to unset the old one, just overwrite the new one
        // setcookie('imgit_style', '', time()-31556952);
        setcookie('imgit_style', 'inverted', time()+31556952);
        header('Location: ' . $home_action);
    }
 }
```

#### Update

This may be the issue... You have no parenthetical groups to logically group this `if()` statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['green']) && $_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'grey' || $_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'inverted')
```

What happens here is that anytime `$_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'inverted'`, even if `$_POST['green']` isn't set, the subsequent code runs and removes the cookie.  Looks like you want instead to group the `('grey' || 'inverted')` together:

```
if (isset($_POST['green']) && ($_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'grey' || $_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'inverted'))
```

Comment: Did this and same again. The first two buttons work totally fine, but invert button does not. :\

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the long conditional you are using, because it makes unnecessary process and makes code untestable.

Consider the following code:

```
if (isset($_POST['green']))
{
    setcookie('imgit_style', '', time() + 3600);
    $style = 'green';
}
if (isset($_POST['grey']))
{
    setcookie('imgit_style', 'grey', time() + 3600);
    $style = 'grey';
}
if (isset($_POST['inverted']))
{
    setcookie('imgit_style', 'inverted', time() + 3600);
    $style = 'inverted';
}
```

Based on the set button, it will set the cookie accordingly. Setting the cookie to `''` will delete it on the user's end, you can fetch this with `print_r($_COOKIES);`, but only after a page reload.

Of course, to check against the `green` setting, you will need to use `isset($_COOKIES['imgit_style'])` because in that case, the cookie will be unset.

By using the above method, this below is just an appendix:

```
if (isset($_POST['green']) && $_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'grey' || $_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'inverted')
```

This is a bit dodgy as you are using the `OR ||` and the `AND &&` without grouping parantheses, giving yourself to the domination of [operator preference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). You should group the conditions based on what you want to do.

For example, if you want to let the condition block run if `green` was set towards POST but the cookie is currently `grey` or `inverted`, you need to use `if ( (isset($_POST['green'])) &&  ($_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'grey' || $_COOKIE['imgit_style'] == 'inverted') )`. As far as I know, this is the default behaviour per boolean algebra:

- First we check whether `$_POST['green']` is set.

  - If `FALSE`, there is no chance for the whole condition to be true, so this is an exit point.
  - If `TRUE`, we check whether the cookie is `grey` OR `inverted`.

    - If either of them is `TRUE`, the equation will be `TRUE` and the conditional branch runs.
    - If **both** of them is `FALSE`, the equation will be `FALSE`, giving us an exit point.